# EntityManager obtained from JNDI lookup is already closed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-5, glassfish-2.x

For (Glassfish v2.1), two RuntimeExceptions from two separate requests from a session bean:

- "org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!"

> org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
>       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1138)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
>    [wrapped] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:76)

- "java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed"

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.util.QueryWrapper.clearDelegates(QueryWrapper.java:460)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.util.QueryWrapper.getResultList(QueryWrapper.java:198)

Both of these EntityManagers were obtained via JNDI lookup (java:comp:/env/TargetSitePersistenceContext)
Using JTA (transaction-type attribute is not defined in persistence.xml).
& SQL Server 2008 w/ sqljdbc4.jar

The code just does the ff:

```
query = entityManager.createQuery();
query.getResultList();
```

And that's it. If I'm not mistaken, I believe the app container will handle open/commit/rollback/close, so we shouldn't have any entityManager.close().

What might have caused those two runtime exceptions?

When does GF actually open/close an EntityManager?

Is there any difference between:

- an EntityManager obtained via JNDI lookup
- via @PersistenceContext Injection? (So far not issues with this style)

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal, a @PersistenceContext injection and a JNDI lookup should return the same EntityManager. So it might be a bug of GlassFish and you might want to reach for them. But make sure to give all the context like type of session bean used for injection, transaction or not etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your bean with annotation `@TransactionAttribute`

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class Repo implements IRepo
{
```

container managed transaction is regulated by this parameter